# find rectangle internal corner points

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image as shown below where I have to find the internal corner points of rectangle. I tried to use **OpenCV** *findcontours* function to get the rectangle boundary and then corner points, but it is not providing the exact point locations which I am looking for  (it is giving external corner points). Any idea or method to resolve the problem?
[image: input]

Comment: try with `CV_RETR_CCOMP` as flag, it should give you a 2 hierarchy list, one from outside and one for the "holes".

Comment: thank you @appi55. It worked.

Comment: @User You can do a lot more with `hierarchy`, like finding contours of same levels, contours having same parents, contours with same siblings and much more !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to use `cv2.RETR_CCOMP`. The following implementation is in python:

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\stack\contour', FILE_NAME))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Don't use magic numbers
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=BLACK_THRESHOLD, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

#--- Find the contours ---
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#--- get hierarchy descriptions ---
print(hierarchy)
```

returns:

```
[[-1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1  0]]
```

**What does this mean?**

Hierarchy helps establish a parent-child relationship between contours. Child contours are those within outer contours called otherwise called parents.

Hierarchy returns an array with the following meaning:

**[Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent]**

[THIS DOC](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) throws a lot of light on this subject.

```
#--- creating a copy of original image ---
img2 = img.copy()

#--- checking whether the contour in hierarchy is a child and if it is then draw it ---
for i in hierarchy:
    print(i)
    if i[2] > 0:      
        cv2.drawContours(img2, [contours[i[2]]], 0, (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]